# Выделение активного пункта меню с ошибкой

Tags: javascript, jquery

При скролле мышкой активные пункты меню выделяются верно. Но при клике на пункт меню и переходе в секцию пункт меню выделяется с ошибкой (на один выше). Подскажите, пожалуйста, где может быть ошибка? Благодарю?

```js
var lastId;
var topMenu = $("#menu");
//var topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight() + 0;
var topMenuHeight = 0;
var menuItems = topMenu.find("a");
var scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
  var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
  if (item.length) {
    return item;
  }
});
menuItems.click(function(e) {
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
    offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top - topMenuHeight + 0;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 1300);
  e.preventDefault();
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + topMenuHeight;
  var cur = scrollItems.map(function() {
    if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
      return this;
  });
  cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
  var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
  if (lastId !== id) {
    lastId = id;
    menuItems
      .parent().removeClass("active")
      .end().filter("a[href='#" + id + "']").parent().addClass("active");
  } else {}
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.wrp {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 150px;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.block1,
.block2,
.block3,
.block4,
.block5 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.iblock1,
.iblock2,
.iblock3,
.iblock4,
.iblock5 {
  margin: 150px 0 0 50px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: darkgray;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="menu">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#block1">Раздел 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#iblock1">Подраздел 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#block2">Раздел 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#iblock2">Подраздел 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#block3">Раздел 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#iblock3">Подраздел 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#block4">Раздел 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#iblock4">Подраздел 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#block5">Раздел 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#iblock5">Подраздел 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="wrp">
  <div id="block1" class="block block1">Раздел 1
    <div id="iblock1" class="block iblock1">Подраздел 1</div>
  </div>
  <div id="block2" class="block block2">Раздел 2
    <div id="iblock2" class="block iblock2">Подраздел 2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="block3" class="block block3">Раздел 3
    <div id="iblock3" class="block iblock3">Подраздел 3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="block4" class="block block4">Раздел 4
    <div id="iblock4" class="block iblock4">Подраздел 4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="block5" class="block block5">Раздел 5
    <div id="iblock5" class="block iblock5">Подраздел 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
var href = $(this).attr("href"),
  offsetTop = (href === "#") ? 0 : $(href).offset().top; // <-----
...
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + 1; // <-----
```